# Python + PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

До недавнего времени работал с MySQL. Теперь хочу приобрести опыт работы с PostgreSQL.

Поискав в интернете нашел множество различных библиотек для работы с PostgreSQL из Python. Какую лучше использовать? (вдруг некоторые устарели).

Нашел: postgresql, psycopg2, aiopg, asyncpg

Comment: psycopg2 и asyncpg. Первое для синхронного кода, второе для асинхронного.

Comment: сейчас парсер на python написан на lxml + request (синхронный) в несколько потоков, затем я перепишу под async + aiohttp, т.е стоит использовать в этом случае библиотеки из вашего ответа? И можно аргументация, почему именно эти библиотеки

Comment: Потому, что это самые функциональные, стабильные и активно развиваемые библиотеки.